# Convert a string as a result of another function

Tags: c

I'm developing a simple code to implement MQTT communication between a client and the MOSQUITTO BROKER. I have a problem with the publish function, but it could be seen as a generic problem of C programming.
The function "mqttPublish" wants a **const uint8_t* payloadPtr**, that is the message to send.
I organized the code in order to send a string and it works well:

- I declared const uint8_t myPayload[] = "payload";
- Then I called myPayload in the function mqtt_Publish in the main.

At this point I want that the message is the result of another function, but I have doubts on how to implement it, because it seems that I have to do lots of conversions. I implemented a function that gives a message in this way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP7a8.png)
Could be it a correct way? The problem is that I can't find any way to call this function in **const uint8_t* payloadPtr**. What am I wrong? Is there exist a simpliest way? The problem is that publish function wants only a uint8_t value.
Any help will we appreciated.
Greetings

Comment: The `const` keyword is a (compiler) informative keyword promising that the data the pointer will be pointing to will not be altered (C allows this promise to be broken). You can safely pass a non-`const` pointer or type cast as needed.

Comment: The fact that `mqttPublish` has a `const uint8_t *` parameter does not mean you have to pass it a `const uint8_t *` argument. You can pass it a `uint8_t *` argument, and it will be automatically converted to `const uint8_t *`. Define your array without `const` and define your function `printto_MQTT` to have a non-const parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to put a new string value in the space pointed to by `message`, then you must not declare `message` as `const`, because `const` means it is a constant and cannot be altered. Trying to cast a `const` type to a non-constant will give a warning. You don't give the calling program source, so I really can't comment any further.